# js/jquery iterate through html elements to dynamically build a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to build a string based on values defined in an html form only if they have been populated.  I've successfully parsed the form fields and dropdown with a for loop ($.each()) but **my ultimate goal is to dynamically build a string with the results**. The string is being used to create a REST query, this is currently the only way to search based on our technologies. Does anyone have a recommended solution?

thx in advance

**sample html element:**

```
<input data-param=" prefix like '%" data-name="prefix" class="prefix uno" type="text" placeholder="pre">
```

**working btn click event loop to capture filled in form fields:**

```
var children = $(this).parent().children('.uno');
    $.each(children, function(i, val){
        if($(val).val() !== ''){
            console.log($(val).data('name') + " "+ $(val).data('param') + " " + $(val).val());
        }
    });
```

**goal**:

```
var newString = field1.param + field1.val + '% ' + field2.param + field2.val + '% ';
translated:
var newString = prefix like '%01%' and name like '%tree%';
```

Comment: just use `serialize` http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Do all children have the class .uno?

Comment: @Martin yes all children have the class

Comment: @DavidFregoli 'serialze' is very close but I don't see how to control the output and ignore textboxes that haven't been populated, is this possible? my string is wrong if/when the blanks get passed in also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks David Fregoli for the jquery serialize reference, that was close, but the solution ended up being to place the strings into a single array, change it [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString), and remove the **','** from the new string.

code:

```
var samp = [],
    thisVal = $(this).parent().children('.uno');

$.each(thisVal, function(i, val){
        if($(val).val() !== ''){
            samp.push(
                $(val).data('param'),
                $(val).val(),
                $(val).data('close')
            );
        }
    });

    itQuery.where = samp.toString().replace( /,/g , '');
```

result search string:

> "number like '%08%' and field = 34"

Comment: you're not building SQL queries in javascript, are you?

Comment: `.join('')` will do the same thing as `toString()` without the commas